# Problema de encoding na importação de projeto para Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, codificação-de-caracteres

Importei um projeto via SVN no Android Studio.

Anteriormente o projeto encontrava-se no Eclipse e quem cuidava do projeto acabou dando commit em arquivos como `.classpath`. A partir daí comecei a ter um problema de encoding que, independente do que eu faça, permanece. Isso vem comprometendo as strings do projeto.

Ex:

```
"Verifique se a conex�o WI-FI esta ativa."
```

Já alterei o encoding para `UTF-8`, `Cp1252`, etc sem obter resultados positivos.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com essa questão?

Comment: Você alterou o *encoding* do android studio/projeto? Se sim, isto não irá resolver. Tente converter o resource (acredito que seja a classe)  que contenha a string com problema para o encoding do projeto/IDE. Caso seja um projeto com `gradle`, por exemplo, você pode congigurar isto diretamente no *build*.

Comment: Tentei fazer isso também, porém não obtive resultados. Sobre o gradle, o projeto não o utiliza.

Comment: Qual o *encoding* padrão do projeto/IDE e qual o *encoding* do artefato com problema? Se for o mesmo, então provavelmente foi aberto em uma ferramente "forçando" o* encoding*, e não convertendo. Daí você precisará editar mesmo =/

Answer (score 1):

Abra o arquivo em questão, botão direito do mouse em cima do mesmo, opção File Encoding. Tente alterar para "windows-1252" e ver se resolve.